# Drools session will not load after Wildfly Upgrade to 19.0.0

Tags: wildfly, drools

I have a drools implementation using Drools 7.12.0.Final that works perfectly under WildFly-10.1.0.FINAL. We are now trying to upgrade to WildFly-19.0.0.FINAL and the drools module will not load. I see this in the logs as Wildfly tries to start the Drools module;

```
2020-06-02 16:31:27,214 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1)  Loading kie.conf from  vfs:/C:/Users/roger.varley/Downloads/wildfly-19.0.0.Final/bin/content/blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/drools-compiler-7.12.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.bls-wsa-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader
2020-06-02 16:31:27,220 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Adding Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl

2020-06-02 16:31:27,223 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Adding Service org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl

2020-06-02 16:31:27,223 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Loading kie.conf from  vfs:/C:/Users/roger.varley/Downloads/wildfly-19.0.0.Final/bin/content/blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/drools-core-7.12.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.bls-wsa-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader
2020-06-02 16:31:27,225 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Adding Service org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl
2020-06-02 16:31:27,227 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Adding Service org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.MarshallerProviderImpl
2020-06-02 16:31:27,228 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Adding Service org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl
2020-06-02 16:31:27,228 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Loading kie.conf from  vfs:/C:/Users/roger.varley/Downloads/wildfly-19.0.0.Final/bin/content/blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/kie-internal-7.12.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.bls-wsa-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader
2020-06-02 16:31:27,230 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieAssemblersImpl
2020-06-02 16:31:27,231 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieRuntimesImpl
2020-06-02 16:31:27,232 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieWeaversImpl
2020-06-02 16:31:27,234 INFO  [org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl] (default task-1) Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieBeliefsImpl
2020-06-02 16:31:27,253 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (default task-1) Found kmodule: vfs:/C:/Users/roger.varley/Downloads/wildfly-19.0.0.Final/bin/content/blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/bls-mrv-de-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
2020-06-02 16:31:27,260 ERROR [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (default task-1) Error when reading virtual file from vfs:/C:/Users/roger.varley/Downloads/wildfly-19.0.0.Final/bin/content/blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/bls-mrv-de-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.getPathForVFS(ClasspathKieProject.java:423)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fixURLFromKProjectPath(ClasspathKieProject.java:368)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:141)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.discoverKieModules(ClasspathKieProject.java:112)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.init(ClasspathKieProject.java:84)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.<init>(KieContainerImpl.java:131)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:135)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:101)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:79)
at de.egf.bls.drools.manager.DroolsStatefulRuleEngine.<init>(DroolsStatefulRuleEngine.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1224)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:484)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:484)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.freshTargetSource(ProxyFactoryBean.java:588)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getSingletonInstance(ProxyFactoryBean.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getObject(ProxyFactoryBean.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1645)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:327)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.freshTargetSource(ProxyFactoryBean.java:588)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getSingletonInstance(ProxyFactoryBean.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getObject(ProxyFactoryBean.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1645)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:327)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
at de.egf.bls.wsa.endpoint.BlsWsaEndpoint.getParameterTypes(BlsWsaEndpoint.java:110)
at de.egf.bls.wsa.endpoint.BlsWsaEndpoint.createCommandTO(BlsWsaEndpoint.java:87)
at de.egf.bls.wsa.endpoint.BlsWsaEndpoint.invoke(BlsWsaEndpoint.java:52)
at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.PayloadEndpointAdapter.invoke(PayloadEndpointAdapter.java:50)
at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:236)
at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-06-02 16:31:27,438 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (default task-1) Unable to find pom.properties in /C:/Users/roger.varley/Downloads/wildfly-19.0.0.Final/bin/content/blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/bls-mrv-de-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
2020-06-02 16:31:27,439 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (default task-1) As folder project tried to fall back to pom.xml, but could not find one
2020-06-02 16:31:27,440 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (default task-1) Unable to load pom.properties from/C:/Users/roger.varley/Downloads/wildfly-19.0.0.Final/bin/content/blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/bls-mrv-de-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
2020-06-02 16:31:27,441 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (default task-1) Cannot find maven pom properties for this project. Using the container's default ReleaseId
2020-06-02 16:31:27,446 ERROR [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (default task-1) Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=vfs:/C:/Users/roger.varley/Downloads/wildfly-19.0.0.Final/bin/content/blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/bls-mrv-de-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
Unable to get all ZipFile entries: C:\Users\roger.varley\Downloads\wildfly-19.0.0.Final\bin\content\blsAccountPlusDE-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\lib\bls-mrv-de-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\META-INF\kmodule.xml
```

My kmodule.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule">

  <kbase packages="de.egf.bls.mrv.de.metervalidation.active.common, de.egf.bls.mrv.de.metervalidation.active.daily">
    <ksession name="DailyMeterReadValidation" />
  </kbase>

  <kbase packages="de.egf.bls.mrv.de.metervalidation.active.common, de.egf.bls.mrv.de.metervalidation.active.full">
    <ksession name="FullMeterReadValidation" />
  </kbase>

</kmodule>
```

I know going from 10.0.1 to 19.0.0 is a big jump but I have no choice in the matter. Can anyone point me to what is wrong. I've seen some StackOverflow posts that suggest that the xmlns should be changed to

```
kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule"
```

but that has made no difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that it's likely in your rules. When it's trying to set up the virtual file system, one of the classes that it's trying to read is not the type you've declared it to be. I think this is one of those things you're going to have to debug yourself. Your xml namespace declaration is correct, though, for Drools 7 (`xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule"`)

Comment: Any suggestion on how to approach this? The Drools version is the same and everything works correctly under WildFly 10.0.1.

Comment: set a breakpoint and open a debug session? my guess is likely some jar/library/etc made available by Wildfly has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was happening in ClasspathKieProject when Drools was trying to use org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile to read the kmodule.xml. This is caused by changes to the JBoss Virtual File System that WildFly uses (details of the fix are at https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/commit/2a36f67a29ed06d0f980a60ff1c81fa897e8147a)

However, upgrading to the latest Drools (7.37.0.Final at this time) fixes the problem.